# How to fix error invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]?

Tags: c++, c-strings

Hi i am a beginner and i have to make a simple phonebook programme in C++ using library . I would definitely use  but im not allowed to as it is for an assignment. Below is my code until now and i have 3 errors which i don't know how to solve. I know conversion from char to const char* is not allowed but i really need to compare these two type c arrays and i can't figure it out how to. I am using strcmp and i am using '\0' as a char which seem correct.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct contact {
char name[30];
char surname[30];
char phone_number[30];
};
int main() {


            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(person.name[i],person.surname[i]) != '\0')   <--- //ERROR HERE
                    cout << person.name[i] << person.surname[i] << person.phone_number[i];
                check++;
            }
           
            char temp;
            char temp1;
            cout << "Insert the name of the contact to delete: \n";
            cin >> temp;
            cout << "Insert the surname of the contact to delete: \n";
            cin >> temp1;
            int check = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(temp,person.name[i]) == 0 && strcmp(temp1, person.surname[i]) == 0)
                {   ^-- // 2 ERRORS HERE CONVERSION FROM 'CHAR' TO 'CONST CHAR*'
                    cout << "Contact deleted!\n";
                    person.name[i] = '\0';
                    person.surname[i] =  '\0';
                    person.phone_number[i] = '\0';
                    check++;
                }
                if (check == 0)
                {
                    cout << "This person is not in your contact list\n ";
                 
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Function `strcmp` returns 0 or 1 or -1. And more generally - an `int` value. The expression `'\0'` is interpreted by the compiler as a `char` (`signed char`, to be accurate). You probably want to change that into a plain `0` integer.

Comment: `temp==person.name[i]` - that is how to compare two characters. `strcmp` is for comparing character **null-terminated** strings. `cin<<temp1` will read a single character. Just use `std::string` for input.

Comment: I am not that sure, what you're actually trying to achieve with `if (strcmp(person.name[i],person.surname[i]) != '\0')`? That's just nonsense.

Comment: And of course function `strcmp` compares two strings, not two characters.

Comment: This code is hopelessly confused and needs to be rewritten from scratch. Honestly there is too much wrong to really be able to deal with in this forum. I had a couple of tries to write an answer but gave up. You need to get with someone who can explain the fundamentals to you. There are many different things that you currently misunderstand,

Comment: You also really need to write less code. There is no point writing 50 lines of code when none of it works. Pick the simplest smallest possible thing to do, write code for that (say 10 lines of code maximum) and get that working before you add any more code. At the moment you are trying to do too much too quickly.

Comment: @john yeah i know i need to learn fundamentals but im a beginner and started using C++ and i find it hard as first language.  Also our professor is so primitive he has said to only use c style strings which just makes it worse. I will just start from scratch as this code is actually really incovenient i acknowledge that. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @Eternal23 C++ as a first language is tough, and your professors views are ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you don't understand struct well, here is a sample I have revised, you can take it for reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct person{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    char phone_number[30];
};

int main()
{
    person Persons[] = { // structure initialization
        {"Bob","Thug Bob","01230123"},
        {"Marry","Gangster Marry","9999999"},
        {"Somebody","Mr Somebody","777777"}
    };

    int Size = sizeof(Persons)/sizeof(Persons[0]); // return size of Persons array

    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++){
        cout << Persons[i].name << "\t"<< Persons[i].surname << "\t"<< Persons[i].phone_number <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

temp and temp1 are `char`s. strcmp expects `const char*`.

I'd suggest using `std::string` for C++, it is a wrapper over char* and has more convenience methods to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I will just start from scratch as this code is really inconvenient. I am sorry for making a unnecessary question.

Comment: Post here just answers.